# Is it possible to make the websites' edit and preview window in two screen?

Tags: support

When preview my editing post, after scrolling down the window, then the window always run up to the edit window, boring.

Is it possible to make the websites' preview window in one of my screen, and edit window in another?

Comment: Related: [Can't see the preview at the bottom of a long post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4213/cant-see-the-preview-at-the-bottom-of-a-long-post)